# Why passing a value in assigns from one controller to another is not working?

Tags: phoenix-framework

I'm changing default CRUD controller actions, so that I have in my `page_controller.ex`:

```
def main(conn, _params) do
        empresas = Repo.all(Empresa)
        changesetEmpresas = Empresa.changeset(%Empresa{})
        scrollTo = conn.assigns.scrollTo
        render(conn, "main.html", changesetEmpresas: changesetEmpresas, empresas: empresas, scrollTo: scrollTo)
    end
```

This handle requests for `/mainEmpresas`.
Then I have in my `empresa_controller.ex` this code to handle the `create` action:

```
  def create(conn, %{"empresa" => empresa_params}) do
    changeset = Empresa.changeset(%Empresa{}, empresa_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _empresa} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Empresa criada com sucesso.")
        |> assign(:scrollTo, "bottom")
        |> redirect(to: "/mainEmpresas")

      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "newError.html", changesetEmpresas: changeset)
    end
  end
```

My goal would be to pass `scrollTo` with a value of `bottom` from my `create` action in `empresa_controller.ex` to my `main` action in `page_controller.ex`in a way that when I redirect to `/mainEmpresas` I have it available there, but I'm not being able to do it.

Also, I would like to guarantee that when there's no `scrollTo` value being passed  `scrollTo = conn.assigns.scrollTo` doesn't break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that `conn` only available per request. The redirection will create a new request by your client and a new `conn` too.
The solution is to overgive the `scrollTo` value as GET parameter.

Call `redirect(conn, to: empresas_path(conn, :main, %{scrollTo: "bottom"}))` or `redirect(conn, to: "/mainEmpresas?scrollTo=bottom")`.

And change your `empresa_controller.ex` to the following:

```
def main(conn, %{"scrollTo" => scrollTo}) do
    # With 'scrollTo' parameter
end

def main(conn, _params) do
    # Without 'scrollTo' parameter
end
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It did. Thank you.